# Write a "IF(A2) IS NULL" in excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I currently write this formula in excel with VBA (it works)

```
Cells(r, c).Formula = "IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,C" & r & ")=COUNTIFS($C:$C,C" & r & ",$" & col & ":$" & col & "," & col & r & "),""PRODUIT"",""ARTICLE""))"
```

Now, I'd like to add a condition to this formula:

if the cell is blank; then return " " ; else, my actual formula

So I tried this:

```
Cells(r, c).Formula = "=IF(C" & r & " = " " ;"";IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,C" & r & ")=COUNTIFS($C:$C,C" & r & ",$" & col & ":$" & col & "," & col & r & "),""PRODUIT"",""ARTICLE""))"
```

I need some help, thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Two situations: (1) Cell has a formula, (2) cell has a blank (or empty cell). Simply get the value of the cell and, if different from empty (i.e. `""`) and different from a blank (i.e. `" "`) it is a formula, otherwise assign an empty string. Isn't this way easier and more readable in your code?

Comment: oh realy? I did not know it worked like that in vba! It's weird because in a "classic" formula  "" = " ". Thank for your advices, I'll try it right now :)

Comment: Let me know if you have any additional issue.

Comment: @Verd'O try the formula in my code below and let me know if that's what you meant

Comment: I don't understand, it worked 20 minutes ago, but now, it writes `IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,C8)=COUNTIFS($C:$C,C8,$N:$N,N8),"PRODUIT","ARTICLE"))` in my cells. By the way i just added a loop `If Cells(r, c - 1) = "" Then...`

Comment: and I changed nothing... ffs VBA language... @FDavidov

Comment: The formula you posted there, have 1 parenthesis too much. Needs to end with only 1 `)`

Comment: god dammit! thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the cell is blank (Empty string), I prefer using `Chr(34)` in order to have the `""` inside the formula string.

So your formula should be:

```
Cells(r, c).Formula = "=IF(C" & r & "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " ;" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,C" & r & ")=COUNTIFS($C:$C,C" & r & ",$" & col & ":$" & col & "," & col & r & "),""PRODUIT"",""ARTICLE""))"
```

Comment: Tanks for your help, but it took 4 * more times to run (bad PC), so I just added a loop `If Cells(r, c - 1) = "" Then`. Thanks for your time again, have a great day

Comment: You should add a space between the double quotations if you want to have the same formula as you posted in your question. `IF(C2=" ",`